# How to give a (new mail) notification in bash/zsh automatically?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, email, notifications

Well, the title of my question is a little vague. Now let me explain that clearly.

We know there is a "MAILCHECK" in bash, every few minutes bash will check the mailbox and give you a message if you have new mails. Note that you don't need a command for this notification. Bash print a message automatically anytime if there are new mails.

Here, I have few questions:

1. there is not such a notification in my zsh (maybe I forget something in my .zshrc)
2. how to change the format of "new mail notification" in bash/zsh
3. how to execute `a certain command` after any of my command is finished in bash/zsh. e.g. when I type `ls` and `<enter>`, `ls` will be executed, and then `the certain command` will be executed. 
   If I can do this, the automatic notification is done!

Is that clear? Any suggestion?

Comment: cool question, btw, I just **had** to give the 3rd a try! :)

Comment: In fact, I'd like to setup a notification system in the shell. I will consider not only the new mail, but also something others, such as birthday of friends, festival, certain information of certain websites, weather, and so on. That's it. Thanks for the advice of you all guys. Your answers are of great help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. Mail notification in zsh:**

I think it's just like bash; mail notification will take place if the shell knows where to look for mail and if the `MAILCHECK` parameter is set to a non-negative integer.

**2. Changing the mail notification message.**

(from `man bash`):

```
MAILPATH
  A colon-separated list of file names to be checked for mail.  The message to be
  printed when mail arrives in a particular file may be specified by separating
  the file name from the message with a '?'.  When used in the text of the
  message, $_ expands to the name of the current mailfile.  Example:
    MAILPATH='/var/mail/bfox?"You have mail":~/shell-mail?"$_ has mail!"'
  Bash  supplies  a default value for this variable, but the location of the user
  mail files that it uses is system dependent (e.g., /var/mail/$USER).
```

I think `zsh` is roughly the same, aside from also exposing `mailpath` as the array version of `MAILPATH`.

**3. Running arbitrary commands:**

In `bash`, the value of `PS1` is printed as a command prompt. Unless the `promptvars` options is unset (it is set by default), the string undergoes parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion and quote removal before being used. The second of those means that you can execute arbitrary shell commands as part of the command prompt.

`zsh` has the same feature, controlled by the shell option `promptsubst` (or `PROMPT_SUBST`, as the manpage says). Unlike `bash`, the shell options is unset by default. Also, you might find that you are unable to change the value of `PS1` (if your distro uses prompt themes), because the prompt theme resets `PS1` before every command prompt.

It turns out that `zsh` has a different mechanism for running shell functions before the prompt is printed (or in other circumstances; I'm just going to focus on this one case). There is an array parameter called `precmd_functions` whose values are the names of functions which will be run before every prompt. (The prompt theme systems uses this mechanism to reset `PS1` before it is printed.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed solutions. I think I've solved all my problems.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know how to go about questions **1** and **2**, but one way to execute a certain command after each command finished in the interactive shell prompt (question **3**), is to add your code in the prompt variable **PS1**.

Here is an example with the date command:

```
$ PS1="\$(date) $ "
Fri Jun 21 22:49:00 BRT 2013 $ echo how cool is this?
how cool is this?
Fri Jun 21 22:49:02 BRT 2013 $
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works well. I am interested in your `Sex` after the date command.

Comment: ups! that's a short for [Sexta-feira](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexta-feira), Friday in Portuguese. Didn't notice the confusion it could cause here!

Answer (score 1):

There's also the `PROMPT_COMMAND` bash variable:

> PROMPT_COMMAND
>
> > If set, the value is interpreted as a command to execute before the printing of each primary prompt ($PS1).

Suppose you want to know if the previous command exited with a non-zero status:

```
$ PS1='\$ ' PROMPT_COMMAND='r=$?;(($r != 0)) && printf "[%d] " $r'
$ whoami
jackman
$ (exit 3)
[3] $ pwd
/home/jackman
$
```